# c++ boost 1.71 compile error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'L'

Tags: c++, boost

I recently upgraded to Boost 1.71 x64-windows via vcpkg.  On a Visual Studio 2017 project that compiled perfectly before the upgrade, I'm now getting this error:

```
2> \x64-windows\include\boost\test\tools\floating_point_comparison.hpp(60): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'L'
2> \x64-windows\include\boost\test\tools\floating_point_comparison.hpp(68): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::math::fpc::is_abstract_class_or_function<T>' being compiled
2> \x64-windows\include\boost\log\utility\formatting_ostream.hpp(562): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt6::basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<CharT>,std::allocator<char>> &boost::log::v2_mt_nt6::basic_formatting_ostream<CharT,std::char_traits<CharT>,std::allocator<char>>::formatted_write<_Elem>(const OtherCharT *,std::streamsize)' being compiled
```

Not sure if the problem is in Boost::Log or Boost::Test.  Here's the offending code in floating_point_comparison.hpp:

```
template<typename T>
class is_abstract_class_or_function
{
    typedef char (&Two)[2];
    template<typename U> static char test(U(*)[1]);  // <- ***
    template<typename U> static Two test(...);

public:
    static const bool value =
           !is_reference<T>::value
        && !is_void<T>::value
        && (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Two));
};
```

There are no errors in the output that pertain to my code.  In fact, I removed all my .cpp source files from the project (just left the header files) and still got the compile error.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: I suspect you have defined a macro like `#define U(str) L##str`

Comment: @immibis MSVC => stupid UTF-16 macros, good thinking :p

Comment: @immibis I checked into your suggestion some more.  Turns out a MS library (cpprestsdk) defined something very similar to what you suspected.  Fortunately, there was an option to disable it and that worked.  IF you want to post a solution, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a macro somewhere, which is something like: `#define U(str) L##str`.

So `U(*)` gets turned into `L*`, but `U` doesn't get turned into `L`.